# jQuery resize() using browser maximise button

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code that fires whenever the window is resized:

```
$(window).resize(function()
{   
    setDisplayBoardSize();
});
```

Fires fine when I resize the window and runs my function just fine, as expected.

If I hit the maximise button though it doesn't work correctly.

This is the setDisplayBoardSize() function:

```
function setDisplayBoardSize()
{
    var width = $(".display_container").width();

    for (i=min_columns; i<=max_columns; i++)
    {
        if ((width > (i*(item_width + gap))) && (width < ((i+1) * (item_width + gap))) )
        {
            $("#display_board").css("width",(i*(item_width + gap))+ "px");
        }
    }
}
```

I think the problem is that when the browser maximise button is clicked it fires the function which reads gets the .display_container width *before* the resize and then resizes the window to maximum which means that my display_board is incorrectly sized.

If I'm right how can I get the size of the .display_container element *after* the window has resized to maximum?

Should note I've tested this in Chrome and Firefox

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***EDIT for proposed fix:***

Here is the [working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DotNetScott/DfKym/)
and here is the [results only demo](http://jsfiddle.net/DotNetScott/DfKym/embedded/result).

As you can see, I totally re-factored your original jQuery code. I removed everything from Global as well as taking out the functions.  [`.resize()`](http://api.jquery.com/resize) expects a function already, so I just do everything inside that one function and then immediately call [`.resize()`](http://api.jquery.com/resize) to invoke it on the initial page load.

Another change I made was to increment your for loop backwards, starting with the widest possible width size you allow (5), working my way down to the smallest possible width size you allow (2).

Also, inside of your for loop, I created `j` and `k` variables to make it easier to read those conditions.

The main change was the if statement.  If we are on the max_column iteration and the width of the container is wider `k`, we want to set the board's width to `k` and jump out of the for loop, otherwise we evaluate the original if statement you had, otherwise if we are on the min_column iteration and the width of the container is less than `j`, we want to set the board's width to `j`.

I tested this in Chrome and it works beautifully. I hope this helps you.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{    
    $(window).resize(function() 
    {
        var item_width = 200, 
            item_height = 300, 
            gap = 20,
            min_columns = 2, 
            max_columns = 5,
            min_width = min_columns * (item_width + gap), 
            max_width = max_columns * (item_width + gap),
            container_width = $(".display_container").width(),
            $display_board = $("#display_board"),
            $display_board_ol_li = $display_board.find("ol > li");

        //console.log("container width: " + container_width);

        for (var i = max_columns; i >= min_columns; i--)
        {
            var j = i * (item_width + gap),
                k = (i+1) * (item_width + gap);

            //console.log("j: " + j);
            //console.log("k: " + k);
            //console.log("display_board width (before): " + $display_board.css("width"));

            if (i === max_columns && container_width > k) 
            {
                $display_board.css("width", max_width + "px");
                //console.log("display_board width (after): " + $display_board.css("width"));
                break;                
            } 
            else if (container_width > j && container_width < k)
            {
                $display_board.css("width", j + "px");
                //console.log("display_board width (after): " + $display_board.css("width"));
                break;
            }
            else if (i === min_columns && container_width < j) 
            {
                $display_board.css("width", min_width + "px");
                //console.log("display_board width (after): " + $display_board.css("width"));
            }
        }

        $display_board_ol_li.css({

            "width" : item_width + "px",
            "height": item_height + "px",
            "margin": gap/2 + "px"

        });

    }).resize();

});​
```

Comment: This is to prevent IE from firing the resize event too often, thereby practically bringing itself to its knees…

Comment: Just updated the OP to say I've tested this is Chrome and Firefox.  Tested IE and got the same result, everything works perfectly but the function seems to fire before the element is resized (or before the element has worked out its been resized).

Comment: Could you possibly create a [jsBin](http://jsbin.com) or [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to demonstrate your issue?

Comment: [Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/Gffda/)   Rather frustratingly it resizes absolutely perfectly when the window is maximised - try shrinking the window down manually so that my display is only 2 columns wide and then maximising. In jsFiddle it correctly displays 4 or 5 columns, in my browser (Chrome,Firefox or IE) it stays as 2 columns on maximise (it'll go to 5 columns is I manually enlarge it).  I should note my screen is 1920px wide so I get plenty of columns.

Comment: I'm guessing there is something in the jsFiddle code that refreshes the code when the window is maximised, if someone could tell me the hook for this then I can just get it to fire my setDisplayBoardSize() function and all should be rosy!!

Comment: if you append /embedded/result at the end of the jsFiddle URL, you can test it with just the results window.  It does only display the 2 when you size it down and then maximize.  I'll take a look at why.

Comment: Additional info - if you manually resize the window VERY quickly then it won't resize the element correctly (still fires the event though so it's just that the setDisplayBoardSize gets the width of the container too early).

Comment: Extra addition : using the snap window feature of Windows 7 it works perfectly and resizes just as desired.  Not sure if this helps at all.

Comment: I added my proposed solution. Give it a go.

Comment: I had to edit the solution again to correct an issue with the min/max columns.  It was doing 1 more than the `max_column` due to `i+1`.  I put some code in the if statement to correct this.  I also put an evaluation for the `min_column`, just incase.

Comment: Thanks very much Scott for taking the time on this.  Great looking code (yeah, I know I had a hefty amount of improvements to make!! Ha ha).  Thanks again

Answer (score 38):

This hapened to me also and didnt knew why, till i read your post. Seems like you were right the function is fired before i pressed maximize, so to fix this i used a litle delay.

```js
$(window).resize(function()
{   
setTimeout(function() {
    setDisplayBoardSize();
}, 100);
});
```

Comment: You, sir, are the only one who actually solved my problem. Your solution is extremely simple and easy to implement. I would give you +100 if I could. Thank you very much.

Comment: Perfect! I set mine to a fiftieth of a second timeout, and it works perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I was having a similar issue on a responsive site where every asset would resize and shift appropriately except for the image slideshow. This only happened in IE, and it only happened when you would start at the tablet breakpoint, then hit the maximize button and enter the desktop breakpoint.

What ended up fixing the problem was throttling the resize trigger using this handy code from Paul Irish:

```
(function($,sr){

  // debouncing function from John Hann
  // http://unscriptable.com/index.php/2009/03/20/debouncing-javascript-methods/
  var debounce = function (func, threshold, execAsap) {
      var timeout;

      return function debounced () {
          var obj = this, args = arguments;
          function delayed () {
              if (!execAsap)
                  func.apply(obj, args);
              timeout = null;
          };

          if (timeout)
              clearTimeout(timeout);
          else if (execAsap)
              func.apply(obj, args);

          timeout = setTimeout(delayed, threshold || 100);
      };
  }
  // smartresize 
  jQuery.fn[sr] = function(fn){  return fn ? this.bind('resize', debounce(fn)) : this.trigger(sr); };

})(jQuery,'smartresize');


// usage:
$(window).smartresize(function(){
  // code that takes it easy...
});
```

You can see his full post about it (from 2009) here: http://www.paulirish.com/2009/throttled-smartresize-jquery-event-handler/

Hope that helps somebody out there.

Comment: Thats really useful.  [Underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) also has a [debounce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) function (possibly the same debounce function?) so if you’re using that it’s even easier!!

Answer (score 1):

some browsers like ie and opera trigger this event with some limitations, this plugin can solve the issue:

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-resize-plugin/

Comment: Thanks for the link, cracking plugin.  But I have the same issue that the element isn't resized by my JS when I hit the browser maximise button, works perfect when I manually change the size of the window though and the function does fire when I hit maximise, it just resizes the element before resizing the window which means when the window is maximised I'm left with a smaller element which means my display board becomes a 3 column gallery rather than a 4 column one (for example)

Answer (score 1):

```
var window_width_check_big = false, // flag true if window bigger than my_width
window_width_check_small = false,   // flag true if window smaller than my_width
my_width = 1221; // Change to your width

function get_window_size() {
    if(window.innerWidth > my_width) {
        window_width_check_big = true;
    }
    if(window.innerWidth < my_width) {
        window_width_check_small = true;
    }   
}

get_window_size();

$(window).resize(function() {

    if(window.innerWidth > my_width) {
        window_width_check_big = true;
    }
    if(window.innerWidth < my_width) {
        window_width_check_small = true;
    }
    if( window_width_check_small && window_width_check_big ) {
        window_width_check_big = false;
        window_width_check_small = false;
        get_window_size();
        // Start function that you need
    }
});
```

Comment: Please consider adding an explanation to the code in your answer

Answer (score 1):

The following code works well for me in both Chrome and IE11:
(javascript and jQuery).

```
function setWindowResizeEndEvent() {

    $(window).on('resize', setTimerForResizeEnd);
}

var mResizeTimer;
function setTimerForResizeEnd() {
    clearTimeout(mResizeTimer);
    mResizeTimer = setTimeout(onResizeEnd, 100);
}

function onResizeEnd() {
    $(window).off('resize', setTimerForResizeEnd);
    $(window).resize();

    setWindowResizeEndEvent();
}
```

Explanation: I'm firing the native window.resize event,
After a resizing ended.
This re-firing the resize event after maximizing the window ended.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works well for me in both Chrome and IE11:
(javascript and jQuery).

```
var mResizeTimer;
function setWindowResizeEndEvent() {

    $(window).on('resize', setTimerForResizeEnd);
}

function setTimerForResizeEnd() {
    clearTimeout(mResizeTimer);
    mResizeTimer = setTimeout(onResizeEnd, 100);
}

function onResizeEnd() {
    $(window).off('resize', setTimerForResizeEnd);
    $(window).resize();

    setWindowResizeEndEvent();
}
```

Explanation: I'm firing the native window.resize event,
After a resizing ended.
This re-firing the resize event after maximizing the window ended.